# Reorder Rows into Columns in Pandas (Python 3, Pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Right now, my code takes scraped web data from a file (BigramCounter.txt), and then finds all the bigrams within that file so that the data looks like this:

```
Counter({('the', 'first'): 45, ('on', 'purchases'): 42, ('cash', 'back'): 39})
```

After this, I try to feed it into a pandas DataFrame where it spits this df out:

```
     the     on         cash
     first   purchases  back

 0    45        42       39
```

This is very close to what I need but not quite.  First off, the DF does not read my attempt to name the columns.  Furthermore,  I was hoping for something formatted more like this where its two COLUMNS and the Words are not split between Cells:

```
 Words         Frequency
the first        45
on purchases     42
cash back        39
```

For reference, here is my code.  I think I may need to reorder an axis somewhere but I'm not sure how?  Any ideas?

```
import re
from collections import Counter
main_c = Counter()
words = re.findall('\w+', open('BigramCounter.txt', encoding='utf-8').read())
bigrams = Counter(zip(words,words[1:])) 
main_c.update(bigrams) #at this point it looks like Counter({('the', 'first'): 45, etc...})
comm = [[k,v] for k,v in main_c]
frame = pd.DataFrame(comm)
frame.columns = ['Word', 'Frequency']
frame2 = frame.unstack()
frame2.to_csv('text.csv')
```

Comment: Can you actually give wither BigramCounter.txt or an intemediary DataFrame, atm it's unclear where you are up to/how we can get there.

Comment: Hi Andy, Where I am right now is the second piece of formatting I have in my question.  I have three ROWS with all of my data in it!

Comment: The problem is that, to me at least, that doesn't look like a DataFrame and I'm unsure how to create it (the same thing you have). Perhaps you could paste the output of `.to_dict()` ?

Comment: Ok -- I updated my question.  Does that make it clearer?

Comment: I still get a different frame here. Could you rip out the stuff at the beginning the findall and stuff, and just have bigrams = Counter({('the', ...}) and construciting frame and frame2. (Also are you using an older version of pandas, older that 0.14.1? That could partially explain the difference)

Comment: would it be easier if i just gave you the entire code?  Because what I am seeing is exactly as I have laid it out.  Also I have Pandas 0.14.1 installed - thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61006/discussion-between-user3682157-and-andy-hayden).

Answer (score 1):

I think I see what you're going for, and there are many ways to get there.  You were really close.  My first inclination would be to use a series, especially since you'd (presumably) just be getting rid of the df index when you write to csv, but it doesn't make a huge difference.

```
frequencies = [[" ".join(k), v] for k,v in main_c.items()]
pd.DataFrame(frequencies, columns=['Word', 'Frequency'])

           Word  Frequency
0     the first         45
1     cash back         39
2  on purchases         42
```

If, as I suspect, you want `word` to be the index, add `frame.set_index('Word')`

```
         Word  Frequency
    the first         45
    cash back         39
 on purchases         42
```

Comment: man, this is truly a lifesaver.  I would upvote this a million times if I could -- you have no idea how many hours I spent trying to get this to work.  Do you mind explaining how this works for me in a little more detail (if you have time?)  Thank you!

Comment: @user3682157 I'd be happy to explain.  Is there something in particular that you're having trouble with?

Comment: This line in particular: = [[" ".join(k), v] for k,v in main_c.items()]  Why did this work where my original line did not?  Also, why wouldn't this work [[k,v,c] for k,v,c in main_c]

Comment: `" ".join(k)` converts the tuple, which Pandas wants to treat as part of a multi-index (in your original post, causing the weird two-leveled columns) or as a literal tuple, to a string. You could have also done `[[k,v,c] for (k,v),c in main_c.items()]` - you need to call items or iterating will only return the keys instead of a tuple of key and value.  This same property is why your original `[[k,v] for k,v in main_c]` was only returning the words and not the frequencies.